# How Do I Deny All files with Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf

I am trying to secure a site to an internal IP on apache.

I currently have the following

```
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

This is blocking access to the main index.html so if I go to www.mysite.com it gives a 403 as expected.

However, if I go to www.mysite.com/login.php then the page is still served (albeit with no css or images). I can still then log into the site, leaving it exposed. All pages once logged in again have no css/images.

How do I block these direct links from being served?

I have tried a deny all for *.php files inside a files tag and *.* inside a files tag, but I get the same problem.

Comment: Apache 2.2 or Apache 2.4?

Comment: Are you using the `httpd.conf` or an `.htaccess` file or a Virtual Host definition to do this

Comment: Is there anybody out there? Either there are a couple of questions that need answering or an answer that if it helped you needs accepting!

Comment: Apache 2.4, Tried in the httpd.conf and the .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<RequireAll>
    Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx yy.yy.yy.yy
</RequireAll>
```

Comment: I get the same effect with this.

Comment: Try putting that code in the virtual host configuration file (/etc/apache2/sites-available/xxx.conf) and restart apache afterwards.